# How to convert the enumerated value as a string value?

Tags: powerbuilder

i am taking the property list of PBObjects/Controls. So i need to take the property. I got the property values throug variable definition.

for ex

```
vd_def = cd_def.variablelist[li_i]

vd_def.name
vd_def.initialvalue // if this initial value is enumerated, then how can i get this value
```

please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What datatype is your variablelist property array?  What datatype is vd_def?

Comment: vd_def is a variabledefinition object(ie., variableDefinition vd_def) and the variable list array taken from classdefinition object.(ie,, ClassDefinition cd_def).

Comment: i tried to change type for ex:

1. Any to borderstyle or any to fontpitch it shows sybase error and it will be terminated.
2. In some cases the above given statement doesn't supports. So we need to give that time like that,
  for ex: 
   any to accessiblerole if any value is applicationrole! then it should be assigned to accessiblerole type value.

Comment: It is worth noting that if you are using a .NET class in your PB application you can simply use the .ToString() method.  If you are using PB enumerated than the solution you found is what needs to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got the answer for my question

using typedefinition object from here i'm getting the datatypeof that enumerated type(it shows the property name). and passing the any value and datatypeof that property name to a function which is like

```
If IsNull(aws_windowstate) Then
    String ls_null
    SetNull(ls_null)
    Return ls_null
End If

Choose Case aws_windowstate
    Case Normal!
        Return "normal!"
    Case Maximized!
        Return "maximized!"
    Case Minimized!
        Return "minimized!"
    case else
        return "!"
End Choose
```